index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' Require stack:
error: index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
Require stack:

D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\index.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.flow.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.js
D:\jd\MyApp\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js

Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets you are using
are defined as dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json
file. It's possible that the missing plugin is loaded by a preset
you are using that forgot to add the plugin to its dependencies: you
can workaround this problem by explicitly adding the missing package
to your top-level package.json.
Project was working fine yesterday. But now its showing this

This question from early this decade suggests trying to add the module again with Yarn. If that doesn't work, maybe edit the question to include your babel_config.js.

Does this answer your question? Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' from /projectFolder
